# I can not create the table structure

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to Postgres needed some help, I created the following tables in MySQL, but am having trouble creating the same table in Postgres, how could I build these tables in the database Postgres?

```
CREATE TABLE `categorias` (
  `id_categorias` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `categoria_nome` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `categoria_slug` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `data_alteracao` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_categorias`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_categorias_UNIQUE` (`id_categorias`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Tabela de Categorias para os arquivos de exemplo do Catálogo';


CREATE TABLE `produtos` (
  `id_produto` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_categoria` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `descricao` text NOT NULL,
  `foto` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `preco` decimal(10,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `data_alteracao` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_produto`),
  KEY `FK_produtos_categoria` (`id_categoria`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_produtos_categoria` FOREIGN KEY (`id_categoria`) REFERENCES `categorias` (`id_categorias`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=57 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: [Ain't no such thing as "postgre".](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE  categorias  
(
   id_categorias  serial NOT NULL,
   categoria_nome  varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   categoria_slug  varchar(200) NOT NULL,
   data_alteracao  timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY ( id_categorias ),
  constraint id_categorias_unique  UNIQUE ( id_categorias )
);

COMMENT on table categorias is 'Tabela de Categorias para os arquivos de exemplo do Catálogo';

CREATE TABLE  produtos  
(
   id_produto  serial NOT NULL,
   id_categoria  int NOT NULL,
   nome  varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   descricao  text NOT NULL,
   foto  varchar(45) NOT NULL,
   preco  decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
   slug  varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   data_alteracao  timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY ( id_produto ),
  CONSTRAINT  FK_produtos_categoria  FOREIGN KEY ( id_categoria ) REFERENCES  categorias  ( id_categorias )
);

create index idx_fk_produtos_categoria on produtos ( id_categoria );
```

More details on creating tables can be found in the manual:

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-table.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html